# <div> not displaying background image

Tags: html, css, image

In my css file, I have an id named "homehero", which displays a background image.

```css
#homehero 
    {
        background-image: url("images/coast.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

In my html file, I have a div that uses this id to display the image; however, the image does not appear whatsoever.

```html
<div id="homehero"> <!-- Home Page Image -->
    <!-- <img src="images/coast.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="A Sunny Coastline"> -->
    <!-- Old line of html that displayed the same image, but converted to css id. -->
</div> <!-- End of Home Page Image -->
```

The full html file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/SJLpQAGY).

The full css file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/5Yhw04Tc).

Edit:
The image is displayed when setting it as the background image for another element, it is only in this id where the issue occurs.

Comment: Because it's blank your main section so May you please set the height of homehero section OR you can add some content under homehero section

Comment: set width and height #homehero element

Comment: An empty `div` with no child content will collapse its height to `0`, and thus won't have any space to render a background image. If your `#homehero` div will remain empty as shown, you might want to set a certain `height` or `min-height` value to it. Otherwise, add content to have it grow taller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest below changes,

```
#homehero 
    {
        background-image: url("images/coast.jpg");
        width:300px; 
        height:300px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Where, your image will be cover and if you specifies width and height it would be good and also your image will not be repeat as no-repeat property is used.

Comment: Not sure how not specifying the width or height at all completely passed over me, thank you!

Comment: For more details you may read from w3school and it will help you to understand it in details, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

Answer (score 2):

**Please Put width and height**
width:100%;
height:100vh;

```
#homehero 
    {
        background-image: url("images/coast.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:100%; 
        height:100vh;
    }
```

Comment: background-size: cover;  "Looks like more better"

Answer (score 0):

These are a few things I recommend you try:

- Try setting the background size. (Instead of %, try setting it to px.)
  Most of the time, the background picture is applied, but because our div has
  no dimension, we are unable to view it.
- Double-check that your picture file is located in the images folder.
- Check your image's extension and make sure you're using the correct one in your code.
- Use the dev tools to inspect the element and see whether the background property is being overridden by another CSS rule.

If none of the above methods work, try pasting the picture's real URL by copying the image address from the internet rather than providing a folder path.
This method works 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're entering the url in the background image, for background size using `background-size: cover;`

If your url address is correct, then try adding

```
width:100%; 
height:100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use inline scope css, i hope it works for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#homehero {.css">
    <style>
        #homehero {
        background-image: url("image/image.png");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
       
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="homehero">
           
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

this might be the reason why it can happen
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-css-cascading-style-sheet/#:~:text=As%20Inline%20has%20the%20highest,sheets%20have%20the%20least%20priority](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-css-cascading-style-sheet/#:%7E:text=As%20Inline%20has%20the%20highest,sheets%20have%20the%20least%20priority).